# XSLT checking duplicate values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an incoming XML like this:

```
<comm>
 <source id ="1">TV</source>
 <source id ="2">Radio</source>
 <source id ="3">TV</source>
 <source id ="4">Computer</source>
</comm>
```

I need an XSLT to make the output XML like this:

```
<comm>
 <type id ="1">TV</source>
 <type id ="2">Radio</source>
 <type id ="4">Computer</source>
</comm>
```

basically I want the XSLT to go through  every `<source>` element and create a `<type>` element. But if the value of the `<type>` element already exists, the XSLT will skip creating the element.
As an example, if you look at the incoming XML the 'TV' value occurs twice; so the XSLT would create the element with the TV value only once.

I am having a hard time figuring this out. I am using XSLT 2.0.

I tried to do this by dynamically updating a variable, then removing duplicate values. But XSLT cant change variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT Removing duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509424/xslt-removing-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

This is very straight-forward in XSLT 2.0, using **xsl:for-each-group**, although you only need to select the first element in each group.

You are checking **source** elements by their text value, so all you need to do is this

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="source" group-by="text()">
```

And to change **source** to **type** is just via a simple templte

```
<xsl:template match="source">
   <type>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </type>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="source" group-by="text()">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="source">
        <type>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </type>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note the use of the [identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), to copy existing elements.

Have a read of http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314 for lots of helping information about **xsl:for-each-group**.